# Append one column to another column

Tags: linux, unix, awk, cat, col

I have two (or more) files looking like this:

```
$ cat temp1
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10

$ cat temp2
11 16
12 17
13 18
14 19
15 20
```

The needed output is:

```
$ cat temp3
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
11 16
12 17
13 18
14 19
15 20
```

So the two columns of the second file should be appended to the first file, like:

```
col1file1  col2file1
col1file2  col2file2
```

Is this possible using awk?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your expected output does not match your described output; please update the question and verify the contents of `temp3`

Comment: You don't need `awk` for this. You did `cat temp1` and `cat temp2` separately. What does the `cat` man page tell you would happen if you did `cat temp1 temp2` together? Try it and compare that to your posted expected output.

Answer (score 0):

*Is this possible using awk?*

Yes, GNU `AWK` can do that

```
awk '//' temp1 temp2 > temp3
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: You could replace `'//'` with `1`. Either way it'll work in any awk, not just GNU awk.